# How to apply SCNVector3 force/impulse from an orientation in scenekit?

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, scenekit, arkit

In ARKit/SceneKit, when the user taps the button, I want to apply an impulse to my node. I want the impulse to come from the current user's perspective. This means the node would be moving away from the user's perspective. I'm able to get the current orientation/direction, thanks to this code:

```
func getUserVector() -> (SCNVector3, SCNVector3) { // (direction, position)
    if let frame = self.sceneView.session.currentFrame {
        let mat = SCNMatrix4(frame.camera.transform) // 4x4 transform matrix describing camera in world space
        let dir = SCNVector3(-1 * mat.m31, -1 * mat.m32, -1 * mat.m33) // orientation of camera in world space
        let pos = SCNVector3(mat.m41, mat.m42, mat.m43) // location of camera in world space

        return (dir, pos)
    }
    return (SCNVector3(0, 0, -1), SCNVector3(0, 0, -0.2))
}
```

via https://github.com/farice/ARShooter/blob/master/ARViewer/ViewController.swift#L191

I have an arbitrary SCNVector, that I've created. It contains info on how high (Y axis), how much to the left or right, and how much forward to apply to the node.

I want to convert/translate my SCNVector3 to come from the orientation/direction of the camera.

Meaning, I have

```
let (direction, position) = self.getUserVector()
let force = SCNVector3(x: 1.67, y: 13.83, z: -18.3)
```

How do I apply the `force` from the location/origin of the `direction`?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out after lots of googling. To convert the impulse vector3 to the direction I need, I used something like this:

```
let original = SCNVector3(x: 1.67, y: 13.83, z: -18.3)
let force = simd_make_float4(original.x, original.y, original.z, 0)
let rotatedForce = simd_mul(currentFrame.camera.transform, force)

let vectorForce = SCNVector3(x:rotatedForce.x, y:rotatedForce.y, z:rotatedForce.z)
node.physicsBody?.applyForce(vectorForce, asImpulse: true)
```

Comment: I am trying same but ball node is not thrown from centre of the screen if I use any value in original vector if I pass only z position then it is throwing from centre do you know anything related ?